# One extra line by default in Arraylist Input?

Tags: java, arraylist, input

I am trying to generate an arraylist in java by first inputting the default size desired of the said arraylist. Then I want to get the user to input the string to fill the arraylist. I have made one that almost works. The only problem is that for some reason I get a default value at the start.

For example, if I set the list length to 3 the list returned is: [,example,value,here]. I understand a value of 3 means 4 values in a list but I feel like that just doesn't look too nice. The problem I think lies in the way I set the size of the list but I don't see any other way.

When I set the list value manually in the for loop I don't get this problem. It only happens when I want the user to input the length. Where is the small error?

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListsPractice {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter length of desired list: ");
    int lenlist = userin.nextInt();


    ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();


    for(int counter = 0; counter <= lenlist; counter++) {
        System.out.println("Enter an element: ");
        String value=userin.nextLine();
        list1.add(value);
    }
    System.out.println("the result is: "+list1.subList(1, lenlist+1));
}
}
```

Comment: counter <= lenlist is the problem either put < or subtract 1

Comment: I tried that but it does the same thing, the list outputted still has an empty value at the start.[   , value1,value2,value3] is what is outputted

Comment: Use next instead of nextLine in addition to using < as Lance suggested

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it. Really appreciate both of you guys' help.